# Matlab segmentation fault when access pointer in Ubuntu

Tags: matlab, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-16.04, coredump

This link below is my original question (More details and source code attached) raised in Mathwork:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/364507-segmentation-fault-when-access-the-pointer-generated-by-mxmalloc-written-in-c-only-in-ubuntu-works

I am using a third party code library: [BDAGL](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/BDAGL/), there are incompatibility issues with the R2017b(the author only tested on R2007a)

Basically I am using two functions in this library:

1. The first function (mkADTree) recursively creates tree nodes using mxMalloc, assigns values to the nodes' members and return the pointer of these nodes.
2. The second function basically takes the pointer returned by the first function as input and tries to access node's member, and this member cannot be found in this pointer which causes the crash.

If using the same code, and I run in Windows it is totally fine, crash only happens in Ubuntu(Linux), the tree node generation process is exactly the same.

All the original source code can be downloaded from the original websites: [BDAGL](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Software/BDAGL/) here.

Anyone ever encountered this issue? Any hints? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please  include your question in your question itself! Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue with a different library, it turns out that MATLAB is not completely compatible with X11 and it core dumps on Ubuntu.

Try the `-nodisplay` argument, if it doesn´t work try `-nojvm`.